# How do I center an image if there is a div on the right side?

Tags: html, css

I have made a header and inside it I have two divs. One has an image and one has a link. I want the image to be in the center of the page but have the link on the right side. How do I achieve this?

```js
function view() {
  document.getElementById('topmenu').setAttribute('style', 'display:block');
}
```

```css
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  header {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1201px) {
  header {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
  }
}

#topbar {
  overflow: auto;
}

#topmenu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<header class="clearfix">
  <div id="topbar">
    <div style="float: left;">
      <div style="text-align: center; clear: both;">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" style="clear: both;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <span style="float: right;"><a href="#!" onclick="view()">MENU</a></span>
  </div>
  <div id="topmenu">
    some text here
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This

```js
function view() {
   document.getElementById('topmenu').setAttribute('style', 'display:block');
}
```

```css
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
 header {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
 }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1201px) {
 header {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
 }
}

#topbar {
 overflow: auto;
}
#topmenu {
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<header class="clearfix">
  <div id="topbar">
   <div align="center">
    <div style="text-align: center; clear: both;">
     <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/santorini-wedding-photographer-logo.png" style="clear: both;">
    </div>
   </div>
   <span style="float: right;"><a href="#!" onclick="view()">MENU</a></span>
  </div>
  <div id="topmenu">
   some text here
  </div>
 </header>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not very useful.  What did you change? Why does it work?

Comment: You're right, I changed the

<div **align="center"**>(here)
    <div style="text-align: center; clear: both;">
     <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/santorini-wedding-photographer-logo.png" style="clear: both;">
    </div>
   </div>

Answer (score 0):

By removing float:left property, your logo will be placed center. However, I'm not sure if your float property is being used for other purposes. I've changed your image for illustration purposes.

```js
function view() {
   document.getElementById('topmenu').setAttribute('style', 'display:block');
}
```

```css
  .clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
 header {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
 }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1201px) {
 header {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
 }
}

#topbar {
 overflow: auto;
}
#topmenu {
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<header class="clearfix">
  <div id="topbar">
   <div style="">
    <div style="text-align: center; clear: both;>
">
     <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.svg?v=f13ebeedfa9e" height="50px" width="50px" style="clear: both;">
       <span style="float: right;"><a href="#!" onclick="view()">MENU</a></span>

    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="topmenu">
   some text here
  </div>
 </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this, just added border to see how they align.I have added the link element in div element and i have added a class which aligns the element to the right side.The div element that contains the image has bigger width than the link div.Also you can set the height according to your image size.

```css
.clearfix:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
     header {
      width: 80%;
      margin: auto;
     }
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 1201px) {
     header {
      width: 1000px;
      margin: auto;
     }
    }

   .img_div{width:70%;border:1px solid red;text-align:center;}
   .right_side{ width:20%;border:1px solid red;text-align:center;float:right; }
    
    #topbar {
     overflow: auto;
 }
    
    #topmenu {
     display:none;
    }
```

```html
 <header class="clearfix">
    <div id="topbar">
     <div class="img_div" style="float:left;">
           <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/santorini-wedding-photographer-logo.png" style="margin: 0 auto;">
     </div>
        <div class="right_side">
           <span><a href="#!" onclick="view()">MENU</a></span>
        </div>    
     </div>
     <div id="topmenu">
          some text here
     </div>
 </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this; done by using flexbox and absolute position only; flexbox will allow you to align items inside a container; but since each element takes some space the usual behavior is that that size is taken into account when centering items, so the image looks a bit to the left side;

By using `position: absolute` on the button we take it outside of the flow of that flex container and align it independently; now the flex container only takes the size of the image into account and centers it horizontaly.

```css
body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.img img {
  display: block;
}

.button button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100">
  </div>

  <div class="button">
    <button>Menu</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or if you want to avoid Flexbox for any reason, applying some `margin` to the image with the button being absolutely position will give pretty much the same result

```css
body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bar {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.img img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.button button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100">
  </div>

  <div class="button">
    <button>Menu</button>
  </div>
</div>
```